# Necessary and sufficient condition for a real square matrix not to have a real eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm looking for the necessary and sufficient condition, in terms of $a,b,c$ and $d$ (which are assumed to be real numbers), for the matrix

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
      a&b\\
      c&d
    \end{array}
\right] $$

not to have a real eigen value.

Comment: NOTE:Given matrix will have real eigen values if $c=b$.

Comment: @ PK Styles , do you know the meaning of the word "work" ?

Comment: @loupblanc:apologies for not showing my trial.At first,i applied the method hinted by AreaMan,but i thought there may be some general statement which states the conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

1. The eigenvalues of your matrix are the roots of a certain quadratic equation.
2. The roots of a quadratic equation have a non-zero imaginary component iff the discriminant is negative; this is "clear" from the quadratic formula.

Comment: :Is it $(a+d)<2(ad-bc)^{1/2}$?I got this earlier,but i thought that there may be some general statement stating the conditions.